# How to check if computer screen is on or off?

Tags: windows

I use TeamViewer a lot in Windows 7 and I want to know current status of my monitor. Is there a command or software to check if a computer screen is on or off.

Comment: The status of the remote host machine's monitor?  This isn't really something Windows is aware of, and there isn't exactly, an API that exists.

Comment: Of course it doesn't matter Teamviewer already has a [solution]](http://superuser.com/questions/440148/teamviewer-without-showing-the-screen/705663) for you

Comment: You might be able to use the WMI Win32_DesktopMonitor class which has a property called "Availability" to determine if the monitor is on or not. [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/969610/sleep-htpc-when-monitor-is-off/1243906#1243906) provides you with some VBScript which can be used to test to see if that property works with your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right Click the computer you want to edit
2. Click Properties
3. Click Advanced (lower left)
4. Click Drop Down under Remote Input (bottom right)
5. Select "Disable Remote Input and Show Black Screen"
6. Log into remote computer from another Desktop edition of TeamViewer and accept the video driver TeamViewer offers

Answer (score 0):

Try to run following command to query the monitor status:

```
wmic path win32_desktopmonitor GET Availability
```

- 3 means Running/Full Power
- 8 means off

But based on my experience, not all monitor supports this API, you can check it on your pc.

More information refer to [this official Microsoft document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(VS.85).aspx).