# ubuntu teamviewer show black screen on remote pc

Tags: teamviewer

I am using teamviewer between two ubuntu system running ubuntu 16.04. I wanted to show black screen on the system being controlled. For that I found a post [TeamViewer without showing the screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/440148/teamviewer-without-showing-the-screen/705663)

But the problem is there is no Actions tab in action bar of teamviewer. I am using teamviewer 13.09865 with free license on both sides. If there is any other way, please suggest the solution.